# Scala App val initialization in main method

Tags: scala, null, program-entry-point

I have some code:

```
object Main extends App
{
    val NameTemplate = """^([A-Za-z]+)_(\d+)\.png""".r

    override def main (args:Array[String])
    {
        // Why is NameTemplate null here?
    }
}
```

Why is `NameTemplate` not initialized within the main method?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using `App` trait, then you don't need to override `main` method - just write your code in the body of the `object`:

```
object Main extends App {
    val NameTemplate = """^([A-Za-z]+)_(\d+)\.png""".r

    println(NameTemplate)

    val NameTemplate(name, version) = args(0)

    println(name + " v" + version)

}
```

It works because `App` trait extends [DelayedInit](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/DelayedInit.html) trait which has very special initialization procedure. You can even access arguments with `args`, as shown in the example.

You still need to write `main` method if you don't want to extend `App`, but in this case it will work as expected:

```
object Main {
    val NameTemplate = """^([A-Za-z]+)_(\d+)\.png""".r

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println(NameTemplate)

        val NameTemplate(name, version) = args(0)

        println(name + " v" + version)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `DelayedInit` trait (which `App` extends) causes rewriting of intialisation code to execute within a special `delayedInit()` method. This would then normally be invoked by `main`. Since you are overriding `main`, however, the `delayedInit()` code is never being invoked, and as such your value is not being initialised.

As @tenshi explains, you can get around this either by not extending `App` or by moving your main code into the body of your `Main` object.