# Run menu item disappear in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have scala code in IntelliJ as follows:

`HelloWorld.scala`

```
object HelloWorld {
  //var matchExample = new MatchExample()

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    printHello()
    //matchExample.oddEven(1)
  }

  def printHello() = {
    println("hello")
  }

}
```

`MatchExample.scala`

```
class MatchExample {
  def oddEven(x: Int): String = {
    "Hello"
  }
}
```

If I un-comment those two lines and try to do run by right-clicking in object I don't have Run menu item, but if I comment out those two lines then I do have "Run" menu item.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your main method signature(un-comment matchExample.oddEven(1)) is incompatible with what Scala compiler requires for a runnable program.

Yours is (args: Array[String])String, the runnable program's main method signature is (args: Array[String])Unit. If you run your code in Terminal, compiler will emit a warning.

```
allen:Desktop allen$ scalac HelloWorld.scala 
HelloWorld.scala:1: warning: HelloWorld has a main method with    
parameter type Array[String], but HelloWorld will not be a runnable program.
Reason: main method must have exact signature (Array[String])Unit
object HelloWorld  {
   ^
one warning found
```

In Scala, if you wanna write a runnable program, you'd better use App trait. 
The post has a detailed explaination on [Scala App val initialization in main method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079713/scala-app-val-initialization-in-main-method).